# Use ggplot2 to create non-solid bar graph fills (i.e. dots, stripes or grids)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I am trying to create a bar graph using `ggplot2` in R. For this graph, instead of using solid color fill, I am interested in creating it with pattern fills such as slanted lines, dots, checkers or other available patterns that the package can provide. The goal is to generate a black and white plot where the bars can be distinguished from one another without necessarily introducing grey as one of the bar options.

I looked through previous Stack Overflow chats and found one that used the `plot()` command in R, but I am interested in understanding how this can be done in `ggplot`

For this graph, there would be 3 bars so a solid black bar and a solid white bar would work, but I want to have the third be some sort of a pattern fill so that it can stand out from the two.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe look into `patternplot`

Comment: And also have a look at https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtextures